# What is the file /etc/crack? Should it be there at all?

Tags: filesystem

Does anyone else have a `crack` sub directory in `/etc` (ie `/etc/crack`)? I'm worried my computer's been hacked.

Comment: Why don't you try the command `dpkg -S /etc/crack`?

Comment: `dpkg -S /etc/crack` will show you which Ubuntu package (if any) installed `/etc/crack`. If no package claims `/etc/crack`, then you MAY have been hacked.

Comment: From a quick google, it might be from package `crack-common`.

Comment: type `man crack` in terminal to read about it. Don't try googling you get a lot of non-software results.a

Comment: tried dpkg -S /etc/crack and got "dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /etc/crack" . It looks like i may have been hacked. What will happen if i remove the crack  directory?

Answer (score 1):

As wjandrea has posited this sub-directory is from the package `crack-common`. The file list that can be seen in /etc/crack from this application's package is as follows:

```
/etc/Crack/dictgrps.conf
/etc/Crack/dictrun.conf
/etc/Crack/globrule.conf
/etc/Crack/network.conf
/etc/Crack/rules.basic
/etc/Crack/rules.fast
/etc/Crack/rules.perm1
/etc/Crack/rules.perm1u
/etc/Crack/rules.perm2
/etc/Crack/rules.perm2u
/etc/Crack/rules.perm3
/etc/Crack/rules.perm3u
/etc/Crack/rules.perm4
/etc/Crack/rules.perm4u
/etc/Crack/rules.perm5
/etc/Crack/rules.perm5u
/etc/Crack/rules.perm6
/etc/Crack/rules.perm6u
/etc/Crack/rules.perm7
/etc/Crack/rules.perm7u
/etc/Crack/rules.prefix
/etc/Crack/rules.prefixu
/etc/Crack/rules.suffix
/etc/Crack/rules.suffixu
/etc/Crack/rules.weird
```

A full listing of all of the files can be [seen here...](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/all/crack-common/filelist) The application `crack` which uses this package is a password guessing program which has been installed on your system.